# Scrot command - how to save only thumbnail

Tags: bash, shell-script, terminal, bash-script

I'm using `scrot` to take screenshots from terminal.

However when I want to generate thumbnailed version using parameter `-t`, I got two files: `screenshot.png` and `screenshot-thumbnail.png`.

How can I get only thumbnailed version - `screenshot-thumbnail.png` because I have no need for `screenshot.png`.

Answer (score 1):

When you use the `-t` switch, it will generate a thumbnail too, not only a thumbnail. You could however extend your command with the `-e 'rm $f'` this will execute the remove command on the original filename, leaving you with only the thumbnail.

```
scrot -t '%Y-%m-%d_$wx$h.png'
```

would become

```
scrot -t '%Y-%m-%d_$wx$h.png' -e 'rm $f'
```